# Drawing both bonds and valence electrons

Tags: chemistry, mhchem, chemformula

Is there any package for drawing valence electrons?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Lewis structures}

Finally: \ch{O=C=O} %valence elec. needed. 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is using chemfig an option for you? chemfig has a `\lewis` command for drawing lewis structures

Comment: @Troy yes, if there is a sistematic way, as you say, it will work. I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: `\chemfig{\lewis{3:5:,O}=C=\lewis{1:7:,O}}` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chemfig` package has a `\lewis` command that allows to draw lewis structures. The `chemformula` package recommends this explicitly as well:

> chemformula offers a command to typeset Lewis formulae. This does not mean Lewis
>   structures! Those can be achieved using the chemfig package...

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usecolortheme{whale} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemfig}  % <---------------

\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}  % <---------------

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Lewis structures}

Draw atoms with valence electrons only (this is fine):

%\chlewis{0,90,180}{O} $+$ \chlewis{0,180}{C} $+$ \chlewis{0,90,180}{O}

\schemestart   % <---------------
\chemfig{\Lewis{0:2:4:, O}} 
\+
\chemfig{\Lewis{0:4:, C}}
\+
\chemfig{\Lewis{0:2:4:, O}}
\schemestop

Finally: \ch{O=C=O} %Here I need \ch{O=C=O} adding valence 
   %electrons also.

Each line show a pair of electrons shared.

\chemfig{\Lewis{3:5:,O}=C=\Lewis{1:7:,O}} % <---------------
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The syntax for `\lewis{<pos_1>...<pos_n>, <atom>}` is simple, with `<pos_n>` being the position of the electrons around the `<atom>` in multiples of 45deg (starting from right-side of the atom, increasing counterclockwise, as we usually do).
You can also explicitly specify with `:` after the individual position numbers to change the drawing to two dots instead of a line.
So `3:` draws 2 electrons at the 135deg angle, for example.

`\Lewis{...}` is a variant that includes the electrons in the bounding box (read the manual if you don't know what that means).

You might also consider just drawing all the lewis formulae with `\chemfig` as well for consistency.